# What is active-trader-pro cask in Homebrew?

Tags: mac, docker, homebrew

Could not find any useful information about it. Also https://formulae.brew.sh/ does not have any cask named as it is.

```
❯ brew install docker
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Casks
active-trader-pro                                              tuist                                                          xtool-creative-space


Warning: Treating docker as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/docker
```

Edit: adding `brew list`

```
❯ brew list
==> Formulae
aom     docker      imath       libavif     libvmaf     ncurses     pcre        webp        zstd
brotli      giflib      jpeg-turbo  libpng      little-cms2 nvm     sdl2        xz
cmake       highway     jpeg-xl     libtiff     lz4     openexr     sdl2_image  zsh

==> Casks
iterm2          visual-studio-code
```

Trying to delete those give the same error:

```
❯ brew uninstall active-trader-pro
Error: Cask 'active-trader-pro' is not installed.
```

Edit:

Following accepted answer we can check out [homebrew docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Taps)

> Taps (Third-Party Repositories)
>
> The brew tap command adds more repositories to the list of formulae
> that Homebrew tracks, updates, and installs from. By default, tap
> assumes that the repositories come from GitHub, but the command isn’t
> limited to any one location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not mean it's installed on your computer, but rather a new package (software) is added to `brew` repository.

If you try to install it, you will see it's gonna download `https://www.fidelity.com/webcontent/CodeweaverInstaller/ActiveTraderPro.pkg`,  which is **fidelity** trading software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did not search `Updated taps` previously. I will add link to `taps` as an edit.